# Conversion of a object into a particular datetime format

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to convert a query string object into a datetime in this format:- "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.xxx" in C#.net. But when i am using Convert.ToDateTime(object) for getting the datetime value then an exception is being fired.

Could anyone can provide me the iFormatProvider for the same.?

Thanks

Varun Sareen

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is trying to convert the `QueryString` object, instead of getting a value from the query string and then converting the value.

A `QueryString` object is a keyed collection of the values specified in a URL from an HTTP request. So if you have a URL like: `http://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3`, the request `QueryString` object will contain three values: 1, 2, and 3. To access the values you would use the keys:

`var aValue = Request.QueryString["a"];`

And the variable `aValue` would then contain the string value `"1"` (without the quotes).

After getting the value from the query string, you can use the `TryParseExact` method suggested by @astander.